# Why does Youtube-dl not download stated bitrate?

Tags: youtube-dl

These are the streams of a video I wanted to download:

`249          webm       audio only DASH audio   58k , opus @ 50k, 1.42MiB
250          webm       audio only DASH audio   75k , opus @ 70k, 1.87MiB
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  128k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k...
*251          webm       audio only DASH audio  **146k** , opus @**160k**, 3.69MiB
171          webm       audio only DASH audio  148k , vorbis@128k, 3.74MiB
160          mp4        256x144    144p  122k , avc1.4d400c, 30fps, video only, 2.98MiB
278          webm       256x144    144p  150k , webm container, vp9, 30fps, video only...
242          webm       426x240    240p  323k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 6.02MiB
133          mp4        426x240    240p  325k , avc1.4d4015, 30fps, video only, 7.10MiB
243          webm       640x360    360p  648k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 11.02MiB
134          mp4        640x360    360p  738k , avc1.4d401e, 30fps, video only, 16.86MiB
244          webm       854x480    480p  983k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 19.61MiB
135          mp4        854x480    480p 1228k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only, 29.77MiB
247          webm       1280x720   720p 1912k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 38.31MiB
136          mp4        1280x720   720p 2348k , avc1.4d401f, 30fps, video only, 53.75MiB
248          webm       1920x1080  1080p 3244k , vp9, 30fps, video only, 67.41MiB
137          mp4        1920x1080  1080p 4427k , avc1.640028, 30fps, video only, 94.91MiB
17           3gp        176x144    small , mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2@ 24k, 2.38MiB
36           3gp        320x180    small , mp4v.20.3, mp4a.40.2, 8.17MiB
18           mp4        640x360    medium , avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2@ 96k, 26.56MiB
43           webm       640x360    medium , vp8.0, vorbis@128k, 34.45MiB
*22           mp4        1280x720   hd720 , avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2@**192k** (best)`

Ok so first I downloaded the last one but when I checked mediainfo of the file I got

Video

_

Audio

- ID                                       : 2
- Format                                   : AAC
- Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
- Format profile                           : LC
- Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
- Duration                                 : 3 min 55 s
- Bit rate mode                            : Variable
- Bit rate                                 : **126 kb/s**
- Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
- Channel positions                        : Front: L R
- Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
- Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
- Compression mode                         : Lossy
- Stream size                              : 3.52 MiB (6%)
- Title                                    : ISO Media file produced by Google

And when I downloaded 251 which should have been 160kbps-opus format (or 148 I don't really know) I got

General

- Format                                   : WebM
- Format version                           : Version 4 / Version 2
- File size                                : 3.69 MiB
- Duration                                 : 3 min 55 s
- Overall bit rate                         : **132 kb/s**
- Writing application                      : google/video-file
- Writing library                          : google/video-file

Audio

- ID                                       : 1
- Format                                   : Opus
- Codec ID                                 : A_OPUS
- Duration                                 : 3 min 55 s
- Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
- Channel positions                        : Front: L R
- Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
- Bit depth                                : 16 bits
- Compression mode                         : Lossy
- Language                                 : English
- Default                                  : Yes
- Forced                                   : No

As far as I can tell the command `Bestaudio`doesn't work anymore with the new update

At least by the last one it says "overall bitrate" so maybe... but the first one was completely out of the ball-park.

I've tried this with other videos and I get the same results... guess I'll settle for the opus one in the future...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

OK I think I've got this figured out. Basically it's not youtube-dl's fault that you're <s>me</s> getting lower bitrates, it's youtube's fault.

Let me clarify, I came to this conclusion because I had the same question when I was downloading youtube videos with vlc media player (which supposedly gets the source link) and was always getting about 128kbps. Basically Youtube, since about 2 years ago, started transcoding all of their videos to 128kbps*.

The metadata that youtube-dl shows which contains higher bitrates is just outdated. (Or youtube-dl's retrieval system is; one of the two.)

(Btw videos that were uploaded between mid-2016 and begin-2019 that didn't get a lot of views (then) still have a fair chance of containing the aac 192k bitrate stream, you just have try your luck.)

Also, someone told me it's possible to get higher bitrates depending on youtube's servers and your bandwidth.
"*If the connection slows down, YouTube switches to formats with lower
bitrates*"... but I'm not sure this has anything to do with the download streams.

---

*(Youtube's gone sh*t basically)